# How to generate list combinations?

Tags: python, combinations

I want to produce a list of lists that represents all possible combinations of the numbers 0 and 1. The lists have length n.

The output should look like this. For n=1:

```
[ [0], [1] ]
```

For n=2:

```
[ [0,0], [0, 1], [1,0], [1, 1] ]
```

For n=3:

```
[ [0,0,0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]... [1, 1, 1] ]
```

I looked at itertools.combinations but this produces tuples, not lists. [0,1] and [1,0] are distinct combinations, whereas there is only one tuple (0,1) (order doesn't matter).

Any hints or suggestions? I have tried some recursive techniques, but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: "I looked at itertools.combinations but this produces tuples, not lists." Converting tuples to lists is trivial. However, `itertools.combinations` is the wrong tool for the job described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`itertools.product(...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product([1, 0], repeat=2))
[(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
```

If you want to convert the inner elements to `list` type, use a list comprehension

```
>>> [list(elem) for elem in product([1, 0], repeat =2)]
[[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]]
```

Or by using `map()`

```
>>> map(list, product([1, 0], repeat=2))
[[1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), assigning the `repeat` to n.

```
from itertools import product
list(product([0,1], repeat=n))
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(product([0,1], repeat=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> list(product([0,1], repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product([0, 1], repeat=2))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> 
>>> list(product([0, 1], repeat=3))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

To get list of list, you can do:

```
>>> map(list, list(product([0, 1], repeat=2)))
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: Great, I just need to convert those to lists, which is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a bit of diversity, here's another way of achieving this:

```
>>> [map(int, format(i, "03b")) for i in range(8)]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```